# How to reload import_module in Maya Python?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to learn Python,

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append(path + 'script/')
    scriptLIST = ['createDummy','importController','matchPosition']

    for obj in scriptList:
        from importlib import import_module
        i = import_module(obj)
        reload(i)
        i.importGroup()
```

I have some scripts, and I want to call them with a script,
but this script give me an error in 'reload(i)',
I need this reload to update those scripts.
Could you please help me with this little script.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few things you ought to consider:

1. `sys.path.append(path + 'script/')` doesn't look right : you haven't provided us what we'd expect to see in `path`, but unless `path` is a complete path string ending in a slash it won't work.  Print out `sys.path` and see what you're actually adding.
2. `scriptLIST` and `scriptList` are not the same -- Python variables are case sensitive. You might have a leftover variable from an earlier run messing up your results.
3. Move `from importlib import import_module` outside the loop. You almost never want to import inside a loop
4. Check the results of `import_module(obj)` so you know if you've gotten what you need. Since you're using strings it would be easy for a typo to mess up your operations.